# Swap first and last columns in matrix

Tags: powershell, matrix, raku

For example, we have a matrix.

```
 1,  2,  3,  4,  5
 6,  7,  8,  9, 10
11, 12, 13, 14, 15
16, 17, 18, 19, 20
21, 22, 23, 24, 25
```

Perhaps the simplest way to resolve the problem sounded in the title of the topic in Perl6 looks like

```
my @matrix = [1..5], [6..10], [11..15], [16..20], [21..25];
@matrix.map:{.[0,*-1] = .[*-1,0]};
```

Result

```
 5,  2,  3,  4,  1
10,  7,  8,  9,  6
15, 12, 13, 14, 11
20, 17, 18, 19, 16
25, 22, 23, 24, 21
```

How to do the same is also beautiful in PowerShell?

Comment: What do you mean by "matrix" in PowerShell? A .Net multidimensional array, a nested array-of-arrays, or a matrix class from some library?

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how zero-effort "please write code for me" questions are getting upvoted here ...

Comment: If you don't mind mutating the original, I would write it as: `@matrix[ * ; 0, *-1 ] = @matrix[ * ; *-1, 0 ];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code snippet translated to PowerShell would look like this:

```
$matrix = (1..5), (6..10), (11..15), (16..20), (21..25)
$matrix | ForEach-Object { $_[0], $_[-1] = $_[-1], $_[0] }
```

Comment: I find it funny that everyone complains about Perl 5, but PowerShell copies one of its most defining features `$_`.

Comment: @BradGilbert PowerShell took inspiration from a lot of languages.